# Xcode UI tests failing to build in CI with error "Could not compute signing task inputs"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, circleci, swift-package-manager

My CircleCI workflow has started failing with an error for which I can't seem to find any documentation:

**Could not compute signing task inputs - operation was cancelled.**

... followed by a reference to a 3rd party library's product, eg.:

**(in target 'Appboy_iOS_SDK_AppboyKit' from project 'Appboy_iOS_SDK').**

I'm using SPM to manage dependencies and I'm trying to modularize my Xcode project by adding a local SPM package.

Below is the relevant part of the CircleCI output.

I can't seem to figure out what these errors are referring to but if I remove UI tests from my scheme, CircleCI doesn't fail and all the tests run smoothly.

I'm guessing this has something to do with the "Copy Bundle Resources" step of the "MyAppUITests" target.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Xcode version: 12.5.1
Fastlane version: 2.187.0

Relevant Fastlane lane:

```
  desc "Runs the MyApp unit tests"
  lane :myapp_tests do
    scan(
      scheme: "MyApp",
      project: "MyApp.xcodeproj",
      devices: ["iPhone 11"],
      cloned_source_packages_path: "SourcePackages"
    )
  end
```

CircleCI output:

```
[00:00:45]: Running Tests: ▸ Touching MyApp.app (in target 'MyApp' from project 'MyApp')
[00:00:45]: ▸ Build Succeeded
[00:00:45]: ▸ 2021-07-22 00:00:45.521 xcodebuild[1629:69156] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-18212/IDEFoundation/Testing/IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder.m:678
[00:00:45]: ▸ Details:  Failed to compute path to baseline file during test run spec construction: <XCTHTestRunSpecification: 0x7fa5036121a0>
[00:00:45]: ▸ Object:   <IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder>
[00:00:45]: ▸ Method:   +testRunSpecificationsForTestingSpecifiers:scheme:buildables:withBuildParameters:additionalEnvironmentVariables:additionalCommandLineArguments:testRerunPolicy:includeClangProfileParameters:shouldDebugAppExtensions:error:
[00:00:45]: ▸ Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa4f9618f70>{number = 1, name = main}
[00:00:45]: ▸ Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
[00:00:45]: ▸ 2021-07-22 00:00:45.526 xcodebuild[1629:69156] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-18212/IDEFoundation/Testing/IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder.m:678
[00:00:45]: ▸ Details:  Failed to compute path to baseline file during test run spec construction: <XCTHTestRunSpecification: 0x7fa50305bb20>
[00:00:45]: ▸ Object:   <IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder>
[00:00:45]: ▸ Method:   +testRunSpecificationsForTestingSpecifiers:scheme:buildables:withBuildParameters:additionalEnvironmentVariables:additionalCommandLineArguments:testRerunPolicy:includeClangProfileParameters:shouldDebugAppExtensions:error:
[00:00:45]: ▸ Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa4f9618f70>{number = 1, name = main}
[00:00:45]: ▸ Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
[00:00:45]: ▸ 2021-07-22 00:00:45.531 xcodebuild[1629:69156] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-18212/IDEFoundation/Testing/IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder.m:678
[00:00:45]: ▸ Details:  Failed to compute path to baseline file during test run spec construction: <XCTHTestRunSpecification: 0x7fa50306a230>
[00:00:45]: ▸ Object:   <IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder>
[00:00:45]: ▸ Method:   +testRunSpecificationsForTestingSpecifiers:scheme:buildables:withBuildParameters:additionalEnvironmentVariables:additionalCommandLineArguments:testRerunPolicy:includeClangProfileParameters:shouldDebugAppExtensions:error:
[00:00:45]: ▸ Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa4f9618f70>{number = 1, name = main}
[00:00:45]: ▸ Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
[00:00:45]: ▸ 2021-07-22 00:00:45.536 xcodebuild[1629:69156] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-18212/IDEFoundation/Testing/IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder.m:678
[00:00:45]: ▸ Details:  Failed to compute path to baseline file during test run spec construction: <XCTHTestRunSpecification: 0x7fa503076680>
[00:00:45]: ▸ Object:   <IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder>
[00:00:45]: ▸ Method:   +testRunSpecificationsForTestingSpecifiers:scheme:buildables:withBuildParameters:additionalEnvironmentVariables:additionalCommandLineArguments:testRerunPolicy:includeClangProfileParameters:shouldDebugAppExtensions:error:
[00:00:45]: ▸ Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa4f9618f70>{number = 1, name = main}
[00:00:45]: ▸ Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
[00:00:45]: ▸ 2021-07-22 00:00:45.549 xcodebuild[1629:69156] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-18212/IDEFoundation/Testing/IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder.m:678
[00:00:45]: ▸ Details:  Failed to compute path to baseline file during test run spec construction: <XCTHTestRunSpecification: 0x7fa503660a10>
[00:00:45]: ▸ Object:   <IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder>
[00:00:45]: ▸ Method:   +testRunSpecificationsForTestingSpecifiers:scheme:buildables:withBuildParameters:additionalEnvironmentVariables:additionalCommandLineArguments:testRerunPolicy:includeClangProfileParameters:shouldDebugAppExtensions:error:
[00:00:45]: ▸ Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa4f9618f70>{number = 1, name = main}
[00:00:45]: ▸ Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
[00:00:45]: ▸ 2021-07-22 00:00:45.555 xcodebuild[1629:69156] [MT] DVTAssertions: Warning in /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/IDEFrameworks/IDEFrameworks-18212/IDEFoundation/Testing/IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder.m:678
[00:00:45]: ▸ Details:  Failed to compute path to baseline file during test run spec construction: <XCTHTestRunSpecification: 0x7fa50366c6a0>
[00:00:45]: ▸ Object:   <IDETestRunSpecificationBuilder>
[00:00:45]: ▸ Method:   +testRunSpecificationsForTestingSpecifiers:scheme:buildables:withBuildParameters:additionalEnvironmentVariables:additionalCommandLineArguments:testRerunPolicy:includeClangProfileParameters:shouldDebugAppExtensions:error:
[00:00:45]: ▸ Thread:   <NSThread: 0x7fa4f9618f70>{number = 1, name = main}
[00:00:45]: ▸ Please file a bug at https://feedbackassistant.apple.com with this warning message and any useful information you can provide.
[00:00:51]: ▸ ❌  error: Could not compute signing task inputs - operation was cancelled. (in target 'Appboy_iOS_SDK_AppboyKit' from project 'Appboy_iOS_SDK')
[00:00:51]: ▸ ❌  error: Could not compute signing task inputs - operation was cancelled. (in target 'Appboy_iOS_SDK_AppboyUI' from project 'Appboy_iOS_SDK')
[00:00:51]: ▸ ❌  error: Could not compute signing task inputs - operation was cancelled. (in target 'Mixpanel_Mixpanel' from project 'Mixpanel')
[00:00:52]: ▸ Testing failed:
[00:00:52]: ▸   Could not compute signing task inputs - operation was cancelled.
[00:00:52]: ▸   Testing cancelled because the build failed.
[00:00:52]: ▸ ** TEST FAILED **
```

**UPDATE**:

It seems that the problem was caused by adding tests from my local shared SPM package into the main target's scheme, as I was looking for a way to run those tests in CircleCI via Fastlane.

There seemed to be no other way to run tests in an SPM package via Fastlane.

I then stumbled upon a [pull request](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/19034) in the Fastlane Github repo which adds the ability to run tests in an SPM package without specifying a path to an `.xcodeproj`.

I separated the SPM package tests into their own lane (and CircleCI job) as described [here](https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/19138#issuecomment-886882433) and, so far, this seems to have gotten rid of the build failures.

Comment: Hey @philtre, I'm running into the same issue with local packages. Have you solved it? What do you mean by "adding tests from my local shared SPM package into the main target's scheme"?

Comment: So, what I was doing was this: I opened the main scheme, and under Tests added tests from the local SPM package. But the proper way to run those tests in Fastlane was to define a separate lane with the `package_path` parameter (rather than the `project` parameter). Check the links I provided in my update to the original question.